# обработка form c enctype='multipart/form-data' в Express 4

Tags: node.js, express

В express 4.1.3 пытаюсь обработать POST запрос от формы с параметром `enctype='multipart/form-data'`. 
Для обработки использовал различные модули типа (multer, connec-busboy), но так и не смог понять как их применять.

Подскажите оптимальный путь загрузки файлов в express 4 ?

Вот ссылка на [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/vaskes/upload-files/src) где можно посмотреть код.

при запуске приложения `node bin/wwww` в консоль пробрасывается исключени
и сервер падает.

```
throw new TypeError('app.use() requires middleware functions');
          ^
TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
```

для мультера прописал только одну настройку, когда её убераю сервер опять запускается.

```
app.use(multer({ dest:'./public/upload' }));
```

#### Спасибо!

Comment: А можете привести минимальный пример кода, который не работает? А то по ссылке слишком уж много всего не относящегося к вопросу.

Comment: попытался уточнить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создал на основе объекта `multer` объект `upload` и передал ему в параметре `dest` куда складывать загруженные файлы

```
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer({ dest:'./public/upload/' });
```

После этого методу `app.post` добавил объект `upload`,
вызвал метод `fields` и передал ему в массиве объект с описанием полей формы

```
app.post('/upload', upload.fields([{name: 'name'}, {name: 'someImage', maxCount: 1}]), image.submit(app.get('uploadDir')));
```

Функция `image.submit`, обрабатывающая этот маршрут в файле `routes/images`, получает файл через `req.files.someImage[0]`, создает дирректори из параметра `req.body.name` и сохраняет в неё загруженный файл.

```
    exports.submit = function (dir) {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        var img = req.files.someImage[0];
        console.log(img.originalname);
        var name = req.body.name || img.name;
        var actorDir = name;
        var path = join(dir, actorDir);

        fs.mkdir(path, function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            var newPath = path + '/' + img.originalname;
            fs.rename(img.path, newPath, function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            Photo.create({
                name: name,
                path: img.name
            }, function (err) {
                if (err) return next(err);
                res.redirect('/');
            });
        });
        })
    };
};
```